# salvar imagem vindo do jquery com o json_encode do PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json

Estou com uma dúvida quando vou salvar as imagens vindo do jquery com o json_encode do PHP.

Tenho esse código jquery para pegar as imagens

```
$('#drag-and-drop-zone').dmUploader({
    url: 'upload.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    allowedTypes: 'image/*',
    /*extFilter: 'jpg;png;gif',*/
    onInit: function(){
      $.danidemo.addLog('#arquivos_cliente', 'default', 'Plugin initialized correctly');
    },
    onBeforeUpload: function(id){
      $.danidemo.addLog('#arquivos_cliente', 'default', 'Starting the upload of #' + id);

      $.danidemo.updateFileStatus(id, 'default', 'Uploading...');
    },
    onNewFile: function(id, file){
      $.danidemo.addFile('#demo-files', id, file);
    },
    onComplete: function(){
      $.danidemo.addLog('#arquivos_cliente', 'default', 'All pending tranfers completed');
    },
    onUploadProgress: function(id, percent){
      var percentStr = percent + '%';

      $.danidemo.updateFileProgress(id, percentStr);
    },
    onUploadSuccess: function(id, data){
      $.danidemo.addLog('#arquivos_cliente', 'success', 'Upload of file #' + id + ' completed');

      $.danidemo.addLog('#arquivos_cliente', 'info', 'Server Response for file #' + id + ': ' + JSON.stringify(data));

      $.danidemo.updateFileStatus(id, 'success', 'Upload Completes');

      $.danidemo.updateFileProgress(id, '100%');
    },
    onUploadError: function(id, message){
      $.danidemo.updateFileStatus(id, 'error', message);

      $.danidemo.addLog('#arquivos_cliente', 'error', 'Failed to Upload file #' + id + ': ' + message);
    },
    onFileTypeError: function(file){
      $.danidemo.addLog('#arquivos_cliente', 'error', 'File \'' + file.name + '\' cannot be added: must be an image');
    },
    onFileSizeError: function(file){
      $.danidemo.addLog('#arquivos_cliente', 'error', 'File \'' + file.name + '\' cannot be added: size excess limit');
    },
    /*onFileExtError: function(file){
      $.danidemo.addLog('#arquivos_cliente', 'error', 'File \'' + file.name + '\' has a Not Allowed Extension');
    },*/
    onFallbackMode: function(message){
      $.danidemo.addLog('#arquivos_cliente', 'info', 'Browser not supported(do something else here!): ' + message);
    }
});
```

Pego o status com o json_encode do PHP

```
echo json_encode(array('status' => 'ok'));
```

Como eu faria para pegar o nome de cada imagem enviada, para que depois eu possa gravar em um pasta?

Comment: Da um var_dump($_FILES) no upload.php e coloca o resultado aqui

Comment: retorna esse erro
Status: SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0

Comment: tentei assim echo json_encode(array(
  'status' => 'ok',
  'name' => $_FILES['afile']['name']
  ));
retornou "status":"ok","name":null

Comment: Faz um jsfiddle.net com seu html e o esse código que envia o upload, nunca usei esse plugin, só preciso ver como ele envia o upload

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t5p1c2s5/ ta ai fiz sem o CSS, pq acho que não precisa pra você entender como passa o arquivo, nunca usei esse plugin tbm por isso minha dúvida

Comment: Cara, eu tava vendo, esse plugin ta sem att a 4 anos, e nem tem exemplos, da uma olhada nesse: http://www.dropzonejs.com/ , muito mais fácil e atualizado

Comment: perfeito  AnthraxisBR !